# pusherapp libraries

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

I'm using the pusherapp service which allows me to easily set up websocket apps.

http://pusherapp.com/

To do this however, I need some server side code to interact with their service.

http://pusherapp.com/docs/libraries

I'm wondering if there's any reason to choose one lang/lib over another. I'm using PHP right now, I can easily swap to node.js or GAE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an app on GAE with Pusherapp. It's pretty straightforward.
For reference, you can check: 
- My fork of Pusherapp GAE library (which fixes some bugs) at http://github.com/macbuntu/gae-pusherapp 
- My app running on GAE at http://github.com/macbuntu/Push-Contacts

I have it working well.